# nouiSlider change input value after update slider range

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, nouislider

I need to update nouislider range, so i do it with code -

```
totalslider_second.noUiSlider.destroy();
noUiSlider.create(totalslider_second, newsettings);
```

But after updating like this my slider input not updating in real time anymore, we drag the slider and nothing happen. How i can update my slider range and change input value like i do before updating (when drag slider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `destroy` on a slider also unbinds all events. I'd recommend moving your event binding into the update loop.